Custom Appbar is bottom overflowed - Flutter
i have designed an appbar and invoked it in my home screen as follows:
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: const Color(0xFF191919),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomAppBar(userEmail: userEmail),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

it always throw bottom overflow, here is the Appbar design:
return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'), // Your logo here
      ),
      title: Container(
        height: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[850],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search News, Teams, Players ...',
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.grey[850],
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 20,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 24,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 4),
              Text(
                userName, // Display the fetched user name
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

The overflow happens at the actions section exactly. i tried to add PrefferedSize() for both places my home screen and the file i designed the appbar in but nothing solved the problem. Thank you

Actions at the trailing of the AppBar are intended to comport icons or icon buttons, not big components. Your column with CirleAvatar, SizedBox and Text was too much to the AppBar height. If you try increasing your title container, it won't overflow, but will hide content without expanding your bar. I recommend your 3 approaches:

Reducing elements size:
appbar with reduced size actions
I've also implemented your AppBar as an extended Widget, so you can use it in Scaffold(appBar: ...)

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(userEmail: "test@mail.com"),
      body: Container(
          color: Colors.grey, child: Center(child: Text("Hello world!"))),
    );
  }
}

class CustomAppBar extends AppBar {
  final String userEmail;
  final imagePath =
      'https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/33252cd1f33526af53580fcb1736172f06e6716f32afdd1be19ec3096d15dea5';

  CustomAppBar({required this.userEmail});

  @override
  Color? get backgroundColor => Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget? get leading => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Image.network(imagePath), // Your logo here
      );

  @override
  Widget? get title => Container(
        height: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[850],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search News, Teams, Players ...',
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.grey[850],
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  @override
  List<Widget>? get actions => [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 10,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 12,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 2),
              Text(
                userEmail, // Display the fetched user name
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ];
}


Making actions inline:
appbar with actions inline

@override
List<Widget>? get actions => [
      Text(
        userEmail, // Display the fetched user name
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
             CircleAvatar(
              radius: 16,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
              child: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 12,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ];


Create a fake AppBar
Just use a full width Row at the top of a Column at the body of Scaffold.

